# How to know if a function is differentiable or continuous on all of its points?

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose you have a function like $f=x^2$. You need to know if on all the points of its domain the function is continuous and differentiable. You are not allowed to graphically imagine or graph it because that would answer the question in the graphical way. I am curious if there is an algebraic or calculus approach for this.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely precise rules for determining whether a function is continuous and/or differentiable without graphing it. For example see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function. This is usually done using the concept of a limit (taught in calculus)

Comment: Do you know the definitions of continuity and differentiability?

Comment: You have to prove it. There are some good rules, for example, composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definitions?

Comment: @gigo318: what you say isn't quite right. There is a precise *definition* (in terms of limits) of what it means for a function to be continuous or differentiable. There are no general rules giving an effective test for the continuity or differentiability of a function specifed in some arbitrary way (or for the limit of the function at some point). There are useful rules of thumb that work for many ways of defining functions (e.g., rational functions).

Comment: @RobArthan fair enough. I should have definitely said definition instead of rules, since as you say, there is no general set of procedures to prove continuity/differentiability for an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of continuity is as follows for point $a$: $$\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=b \land f(a)=b.$$ Here $b,x,a$ are real numbers.

Unpacking the limit definition we have ($\epsilon, \delta$ are positive real numbers)
$$\forall \epsilon \space \exists \delta: |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon, \space \space |x-a|<\delta$$

Well, one thing you can prove (I am almost certain you will find the proof in stack exchange) that composition of continuous functions is continuous. Multiplication is also continuous in the case that the zeros of the continuous functions agree. Further, all polynomials are continuous. This way it is easy to come to the conclusion that $x^2$ is continuous.

However, one way is of course to prove it directly. Trivial in this case. Choose an $\epsilon$, then we may choose $\delta =  \text{min}( 1,\frac{\epsilon}{(1+2|a|)})$, now

$$|x^2-a^2| = |x+a||x-a|\leq (1+|2a|)|x-a|<\epsilon, \space \space |x-a|<\text{min}( 1,\frac{\epsilon}{(1+2|a|)})$$